# How do I apply realistic force and torque in relation to a center of mass?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics, unity3d-2dtools

Taking [Captain Forever](http://www.captainforever.com/captainforever.php) as an example as well as [this](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-torque-and-thrusters-to-move-and-rotate-a-player-designed-spaceship--gamedev-2610) tutorial, how would I achieve similar movement? I've found a couple of answers to this question, but I can't quite seem to get them to work for me. I have a parent ridgidbody and two child thruster rigidbodies with the following applied to each.

```
X = transform.position.x;
Y = transform.position.y;
pos = new Vector2(X, Y);

// Should I be using these anywhere?
float angle = Mathf.Deg2Rad * Vector2.Angle(direction, forward);
Vector2 direction = COM - pos;

Vector2 forward = transform.up * force;
Vector2 distToCOM = pos - COM;
float torque = distToCOM.magnitude * forward;

if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
{
    parentRB.AddForceAtPosition(torque,pos);
}

if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
{
// Not done yet
}
```

Quite a bit of guesswork has gone into this (and I realise some of the code is a bit crude), maths was never my strong point! I have a feeling the torque and force should be vectors, but I'm not sure how to calculate them properly.

Would appreciate any help you can give, thanks!

EDIT: I've made a few changes and I think I've managed to get it a bit closer with the above, but still getting some wonky movement.

Comment: Torque is the cross product of the distance to center of mass and your force vector, rather than a scalar multiply. i.e. float torque = Vector3.Cross(distToCOM, forward).z

Comment: Ok, I just read the bit where you're feeding a torque into AddForceAtPosition(). That's where your force vector should go instead, and if you're using AddForceAtPosition() Unity will apply torque for you.